# How to create an empty array in PHP with predefined size?

Tags: php, arrays

I am creating a new array in a for loop.

```
for $i < $number_of_items
    $data[$i] = $some_data;
```

PHP keeps complaining about the offset since for each iteration I add a new index for the array, which is kind of stupid.

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in include() (line 23 of /...
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in include() (line 23 of /..
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in include() (line 23 of /..
```

---

Is there some way to predefine the number items in the array so that PHP will not show this notice?

In other words, can I predefine the size of the array in a similar way to this?

```
$myarray = array($size_of_the_earray);
```

Comment: PHP shouldn't be complaining when you're assigning to those indices.

Comment: Could you provide actual code that produces the error? The code supplied is invalid. You should not get an undefined offset error from an array when setting an index value.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

There is no way to create an array of a predefined size without also supplying values for the elements of that array.

---

The best way to initialize an array like that is [`array_fill`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php). By far preferable over the various loop-and-insert solutions.

```php
$my_array = array_fill(0, $size_of_the_array, $some_data);
```

Every position in the `$my_array` will contain `$some_data`.

The first zero in `array_fill` just indicates the index from where the array needs to be filled with the value.

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in include() (line 23 of / 
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in include() (line 23 of /
...

Comment: @Reed: This sounds like you are trying to read from the array, while your example code looks like you 're trying to *write*. Which one is it?

Comment: You were right. In the same line of the code I was reading from another array which thought was ok. Lesson learned don't code after bed time...thanks!

Comment: @Reed, this is why we request the actual code being run.  It makes it easier for us to provide useful, accurate answers.

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is not at all helpful. Seeding an array with values is a common use case in programming.

Comment: @peterjwest of course, but the fact is you cannot "create an empty array with predefined size" in PHP. I'm not sure what kind of answer you expect in this situation.

Comment: Okay I do see what you mean, the wording of the question isn't ideal. A better start to the answer might be "It isn't possible have an array in PHP that has a length different to the number of values in the array. Each value must be defined before being accessed, or guarded with a an `isset` check"

Comment: I've tried to come up with a better wording than "There is not a way to do that." please check if it is correct. I've also removed some fluff as "For posterity". I can only hope that that sentence is still fluff, anyway, please review changes if it is fluff.

Comment: If you initialize all values as null then technically it is an empty array like in C or Java. array_fill (0 , $num , null)

Answer (score 25):

Potentially relevant- if you want to initialize and fill an array with a range of values, use PHP's (wait for it...) [range function](https://www.php.net/range):

```
$a = range(1, 5);  // array(1,2,3,4,5)
$a = range(0, 10, 2); // array(0,2,4,6,8,10)
```

Answer (score 19):

You can't predefine a size of an array in php. A good way to acheive your goal is the following:

```
// Create a new array.
$array = array(); 

// Add an item while $i < yourWantedItemQuantity
for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_items; $i++)
{
    array_push($array, $some_data);
    //or $array[] = $some_data; for single items.
}
```

Note that it is way faster to use array_fill() to fill an Array :

```
$array = array_fill(0,$number_of_items, $some_data);
```

If you want to verify if a value has been set at an index, you should use the following:
array_key_exists("key", $array) or isset($array["key"])

See [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)
, 
[isset](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)
and
[array_fill](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)

Comment: Note that the shorthand `$array[] = $some_data` is faster than `array_push()` for single items

Answer (score 5):

[PHP Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) don't need to be declared with a size.

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map

You also shouldn't get a warning/notice using code like the example you have shown. The common  Notice people get is "Undefined offset" when reading from an array.

A way to counter this is to check with `isset` or `array_key_exists`, or to use a function such as:

```
function isset_or($array, $key, $default = NULL) {
    return isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : $default;
}
```

So that you can avoid the repeated code.

Note: `isset` returns false if the element in the array is NULL, but has a performance gain over `array_key_exists`.

If you want to specify an array with a size for performance reasons, look at:

[SplFixedArray](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php) in the Standard PHP Library.

Comment: I am trying to understand why is the default PHP array not optimized for performance. The manual says, it is actually an ordered map. How different is that from a hash map or hash table? The concept of a hash table is clear to me, the way it is optimized for scalability as well as random access, however, a hash map is still not clear.

Comment: It is performant, but it won't always be as performant as an array that has a specified size.

Comment: As of PHP 7, numeric ascending arrays are no longer stored as ordered maps. They're stored internally as C arrays.

Answer (score 5):

There is also [array_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php). You can use it like this:

```
$data = array_pad($data,$number_of_items,0);
```

For initializing with zeros the $number_of_items positions of the array $data.

Answer (score 5):

```
 $array = new SplFixedArray(5);
   echo $array->getSize()."\n";
```

You can use  PHP documentation more info check this link
https://www.php.net/manual/en/splfixedarray.setsize.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP provides two types of array.

- normal array
- SplFixedArray

normal array : This array is dynamic.

SplFixedArray : this is a standard php library which provides the ability to create array of fix size.