# Quickly create large arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create an empty array in PHP with predefined size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385433/how-to-create-an-empty-array-in-php-with-predefined-size)

In a C-based language, you can very quickly create a large multi-dimensional array that you might use in conjunction with loops for an algorithm or something. Like so:

```
int foo[50][40];
```

In PHP, how can you do this? At the moment, the only way I can think of is this:

```
$bar = array();
for ($a = 0; $a<50; $a++) {
    for ($b = 0; $b++; $b<40) {
        $bar[$a][$b] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Polity true - I did search, wasn't looking for the right thing though - have voted to close!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, you don't have to predefine the size of your array, you can dynamically append it with data, like so:

```
$bar = array();
for($i = 0;$i < 50;$i++) {
    $bar[] = $i;
}
```

By calling the $bar with [], you'll indicate that a new key should be created and in this case hold value $i.

Comment: the QA already posted this solution in his question...

Comment: @Polity Not entirely. OP is assuming that array construction is similar to the C-way, I'm just demonstrating that it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Using [SplFixedArray](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php) will speed that up (and also make it occupy less memory).

Comment: +1 for SplFixedArray.... though it has its limitations, particularly if creating multi-dimensional arrays

Answer (score 0):

in PHP-based language you don't need to create arrays "in reserve".
But just add whatever number of elements you need on the fly, as soon as you need it.

BTW, if speed means not the concise code but the speed of the execution, PHP is already a wrong choice for sure.

Comment: this is not practical in many cases where you are not accessing indexes in a predefined order

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$bar = range(0, 50);
foreach ($bar as $k => $v) {
    $bar[$k] = range(0, 40);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this one can help:

```
    $b = array_fill(0,50,0);
    $a = array_fill(0,50,$b);
//and so on, depending on how many dimensions do you need
```