# Converting C# code to PHP : Create empty byte array php and send using socket

Tags: c#, php, sockets

```
//how to initialize byte[10240] in php  
var svr = new TcpClient();
svr.Connect(127.0.0.1, 8081);
var ns = svr.GetStream();
var outputBuffer = new byte[10240];
var pkgLen = 11
ns.Write(outputBuffer, 0, pkgLen);
```

I have the above C# code an I am trying to convert the code to PHP.
Here is my code in php:

```
<?php    
/* Create a TCP/IP socket. */
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

$message = //empty array of byte    
socket_send($socket, $message);

socket_close($socket)
?>
```

My question is how to create an empty array of byte of length 10240 in php? 
**Also the socket_send function takes a string not an array.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an empty array in PHP with predefined size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385433/how-to-create-an-empty-array-in-php-with-predefined-size)

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a string with a zero byte in it, and then you need to essentially multiply it.

```php
$zero = chr(0);
$message = str_repeat($zero, 10240);
```

You could also use `str_pad`:

```php
$message = str_pad('', 10240, chr(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

What protocol requires you to write 10240 null bytes?

Anyway, the `Write()` overload you call only writes the first 11 (`pkgLen`) bytes of that array. So you need to write 11 zeroes.

You can do that hardcoded:

```
$message = "\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0";
```