# C# New byte[] PHP equivalent

Tags: c#, php

I'm trying to replicate a C# piece of code in PHP and can't figure out this next line:

```
var digestBytes = new byte[nonceBytes.Length + createdBytes.Length + passwordBytes.Length];
```

Is there any `new byte[length]` equivalent for PHP?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an empty array in PHP with predefined size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385433/how-to-create-an-empty-array-in-php-with-predefined-size)

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't have a byte type, but you could use an array of ints instead

```
$some_data = 0;
$length = 3;
$bytes = array_fill(0, $length, $some_data);
```